# Trying to create a qr code in an email using meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, html-email, qr-code, meteor-blaze

I am using [an AngularJS package](https://atmospherejs.com/yasseraudio/angular-qrcode-generator) to create QR codes

I want to add the code to an email which I am sending users after they purchase something as a ticket id.

This is my email template:

```
<template name="TicketEmail">
    <p> Hi {{name}}!</p>
    <p> Thank you for purchasing your ticket to {{eventName}}</p>
    <p> Your ticket ID is {{ticketID}}.</p>
    <qrcode class='qrcode' version="{{version}}" error-correction-level="{{level}}" size="{{size}}" data="{{var}}"></qrcode>
</template>
```

And here is how I and generating the HTML and sending the email:

```
var data = {
    name: "John",
    eventName: "Music and Stuff",
    ticketID: '12345',
    version: '4',
    level: 'M',
    size: '200',
    var: '12345'
};
var html = Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(data, function() {
    return Template.TicketEmail;
}));

var options = {
    from: "John Doe <johndoe@gmail.cm>",
    to: "Mike Smith <mikesmith@gmail.com>",
    subject: "Ticket Purchase",
    html: html,
};

Meteor.call("sendEmail", options);
$(".popup-bg").fadeOut("slow");
```

The email sends fine but the QR code does not show up.

Comment: My first instinct is to ask for a sample of the compiled email code. Is the QR image generated being stored on an accessible web server? If it's generating a local file and the HREF to it is relative, the link will be broken.

Comment: Did you fix this issue then?